# Is there any library available in android for converting .txt file to different formats(.doc,.docx)

Tags: android, text, converters, .doc

In my projects i have to convert a .txt file to .doc and .docx format. Is there any library available in android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you searched or tried any thing ?>/

Comment: i go through this link http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component.aspx

Comment: ok what are the issues facing on that?

Comment: Hey, As per my knowledge, You can convert your text file to Excel and Pdf format and come to know that Text file can't be converted in .doc or .docx in Android.